# PHP SimpleXMLElement: Count isn't counting all public properties of the Object

Tags: php, object, simplexml

I have the following code:

```
$b = $br->b;
var_dump($b);
$iCountBlock = count($b);
```

Where b is a SimpleXMLElement object. The var dump outputs:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
public 'blockID' => string '160999' (length=6)
public 'blockDesc' => string 'Description' (length=37)
public 'moduleID' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'pubID' => 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
public 'contentID' => string '93305' (length=5)
public 'linkToPageID' => 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
public 'moduleFunction' => string 'replaceHTML' (length=11)
public 'moduleVars' => 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[20]
public 'c' => 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
    public 'contentID' => string '93305' (length=5)
    public 'contentType' => string '1' (length=1)
    public 'description' => string 'new.usdish.com index redesign content' (length=37)
    public 'content' => 
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[22]
```

However, $iCountBlock gets set to 1... it doesn't appear to be counting all the public properties of the object as it should. I also tried using a foreach loop to loop over each property of b and it didn't even enter the loop.

```
foreach($b as $key => $val) { ... }
```

I'm kinda at a loss here, as I'm not sure what's going on. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form PHP 5.3 and higher SimpleXMLElement does use a count **function** for the length!

```
$count = $b->count();
```

In PHP before 5.3 you have to use the childern property for getting the count.

```
$count = count($b->children());
```

Info at: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find this same answer in the PHP Manuals and I have tested it and it's working. The server I'm deploying to has PHP 5.1 (It's RHEL), so I'm using the second method.

Comment: Note that the reason this is necessary is because your variable `$b` is a *list of all children named `<b>`*. So `count()` returns the number of items in that list, not the number of children. The extra call to `$b->children()` is equivalent to `$b[0]->children()` - it gives you a new list, containing all children of the first item in the old list.